# Can a Tactical Insertion be destroyed by another player?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I'm intrigued by Tactical Insertion. It seems it could be very fun in some game types. I've never really seen it used though, in game.

**Can other players see your Tactical Insertion? If so can they destroy it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tactical insertion can be destroyed by an opponent when it's found. It can be found significantly easier with the 'hacker' perk.  In addition to that, enemy players will sometimes claymore or camp a tactical insertion for a free kill.  There is a 'cancel' tactical insertion button, but the actual functionality of it seems to be very flawed (so don't rely on it).

The power of the tactical insertion should not be underestimated though.  Specifically in tactical games (capture the flag comes to mind) you can lay your tactical insertion near your objective and muscle your way in.  I have also found it very useful in maps with questionable spawns (like Nuketown) as it can prevent you from getting repeatedly spawn killed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can see them although they're really hard to see without hacker pro. And you can destroy them with lots of things.

They're mainly useful in objective based games. 
A good example is demolition. What me and my team will often do is put out tactical insertions close to the bombs plant. This allows us to return back to defending/attacking the bomb more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

They can see it; people with the Hacker perk can even see it highlighted.

In CoD: MW2, you could destroy them. I have never seen one in Black Ops, so I never could test it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and Yes on both questions.

Regarding fun/value: not so much. Maps are too small and respawn system is pretty borked right now for this feature to have any serious use.

Comment: When an enemy sees it is it glowing like it does from my point of view?

Comment: I don't think so, unless they have hacker perk. Not 100% sure though.